# Changes b/w ElasticSearch 1.x and 2.x

Tags: nest

Does documentation exist on how to change code written in NEST 1.x to 2.x?

I've looked at these sites and they're incomplete:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes/nest-breaking-changes.md

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net

https://www.elastic.co/blog/ga-release-of-nest-2-0-our-dot-net-client-for-elasticsearch

For example I'd like to know how to replace the following:

1)

```
given ISearchResponse<T>  searchResults = ...
```

How to do:

```
searchResults.ConnectionStatus 
searchResults.RequestInformation.Request
```

2)

```
client.Get<T>(s => s.Id(id));
```

3)
Given `QueryContainer query`

```
new SearchDescriptor<T>()
            .From(from)     
            .Size(pageSize)   
            .Query(query); //this dosen't work anymore
```

4)
MatchQuery doesn't accept fuziness as double and type parameters as string as it used to

5) QueryDescriptor seems gone *gasp*

6) client.Update is busted

```
 var result = client.Update<CustomerProfile>(request => request
                .Id(customer.CustomerId)
                .Doc(customer)
                .Refresh()
                );
```

7) client.Get is busted in a similar way to client.Update

8) In Mappings the following setup doesn't work anymore

```
CreateIndexDescriptor cid = ...
cid.NumberOfReplicas(numReplicas)
     .NumberOfShards(numShards)
     .Settings(s => s
         .Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")
         .Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s")
     )
     .Analysis(a => a.TokenFilters etc etc
```

---

EDIT

9) Date Ranges:
startDate and endDate are DateTime type

```
var qd = new QueryContainerDescriptor<EsActivity>();
        QueryContainer qc = qd.Range(r =>
                    r.Field("esactivity.timestamp")
                    .GreaterThanOrEquals(DateMath.Anchored(startDate))
                    .LessThanOrEquals(DateMath.Anchored(endDate))
                );
```

`.GreaterThanOrEquals` expects a `double` parameter but on the documentation page it takes `DateMath.Anchored(startDate)`

10) Highlighting:

```
highlightFields: List<string> 
Action<HighlightFieldDescriptor<T>> [] tmp = highlightFields.Select(field =>
                          new Action<HighlightFieldDescriptor<T>>(
                              highlighter => highlighter.Field(field)
                          )
                      ).ToArray();

sd:SearchDescriptor<..>..
sd.Highlight(h => h
                      .PreTags(preTag)
                      .PostTags(postTag)
                      .OnFields(tmp)
                   );
```

I see I can replace `OnFields(tmp)` with `.Fields(f=>f.OnAll())` but I'd still like to specify the fields myself in some way.

And how come there is a HighlightQuery option available since we already apply highlighting on a query object.. now there are 2 query calls.

I've converted the highlighting above to

```
            var tmp = highlightFields.Select(field =>
                          Tuple.Create<Field, IHighlightField>(
                              Field.Create(field),
                              new HighlightField()
                          )
                       ).ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);

            sd.Highlight(h => new Highlight
                {
                    PreTags = new[] { preTag },
                    PostTags = new[] { postTag },
                    Fields = tmp
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `searchResults.ApiCall` replaces `searchResults .ConnectionStatus`.

You can get the request bytes with `searchResults.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes` and you will also need to set `.DisableDirectStreaming()` on `ConnectionSettings` in order to capture the bytes as the request is written to the request stream directly by default.

2) Use `client.Get<T>(id)` - The first parameter is a [`DocumentPath<T>` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/document-paths.html).

3) To pass a `QueryContainer` to a Fluent API descriptor, just return it from the `Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer>`

```
new SearchDescriptor<T>()
    .From(from)     
    .Size(pageSize)   
    .Query(_ => query);
```

4) `match` query fuzziness as a `double` [mapped to a formula to calculate edit distance in Elasticsearch 1.x.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/common-options.html#_string_fields) Since this was removed in Elasticsearch 2.x, it is also gone from NEST. You can set fuzziness edit distance with

```
client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Query("this is my query")
            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(3))
        )
    )
);
```

Not sure what you're referring to with `type`, but I think you're referring to document type? If that's the case, document type takes a `Types` type which `string` implicitly converts to

```
client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Type("other-type")
    .MatchAll()
);
```

5) `QueryDescriptor<T>` was renamed to `QueryContainerDescriptor<T>` to better reflect the fact that it's a descriptor for building a `QueryContainer`

6) Update API works

```
// specifying id
client.Update<Document>("document-id", u => u
    .Doc(document)
    .Refresh()
);
```

Since the first parameter is a `DocumentPath<T>`, the document instance (if you have it) can be passed as the first parameter

```
client.Update<Document>(document, u => u
    .Doc(document)
    .Refresh()
);
```

where index, type and id will be inferred from the document instance

7) See above

8) Create index settings have been revised to reflect the level at which the settings appear in the REST API json call

```
client.CreateIndex("index-name", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .NumberOfShards(2)
        .NumberOfReplicas(2)
        .SlowLog(sl => sl
            .Search(sls => sls
                .Fetch(slsf => slsf
                    .ThresholdWarn("1s")
                )
            )
        )
        .Analysis(a => a) // etc...
    )
);
```

You can also use strings for settings if you prefer, although the fluent API will ensure the correct setting values are sent e.g. `"search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn"` is now [`"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/index-modules-slowlog.html)

```
client.CreateIndex("index-name", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .NumberOfShards(2)
        .NumberOfReplicas(2)
        .Setting("index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s")
        .Analysis(a => a) // etc...
    )
);
```

[`merge.policy.merge_factor` is removed in Elasticsearch 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/breaking_20_setting_changes.html#_merge_and_merge_throttling_settings)

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to answer this; I'm having similar trouble with DataRange query and Highlighting - updating question with those

Comment: That's 10 questions in one :) Might be worth opening other questions as it'll make it easier for others in the future with similar questions to find the answers.